# How to recompile directive attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a custom directive called "esf-cb", and I uses another custom directive on the same element to add a localized resource.
the "esf-cb" directive code is :

```
.directive('esfCb', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        custId: '@',
        custLabel: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/custominput/checkbox.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcFun) {
        //alert('post cb');
        transcFun(function (cloned) {
            //scope.type = angular.element(cloned[1]).attr('type') == 'checkbox' ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';
            element.find('placeholder').replaceWith(cloned);
        })
    }
}
})
```

and it's used as:

```
<esf-cb cust-id="{{input.id}}" resource-key="fnLabel" resource-attr="cust-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="input.isChecked" id="{{input.id}}" ng-disabled="input.isDisabled" name="group-cb" class="toggler-input" />
                    </esf-cb>
```

where the directive template is :

```
<div role="checkbox" class="custom-input">
    <placeholder></placeholder>
    <label for="{{custId}}" class="toggler-btn">{{custLabel}}</label>
    <div class="toggler-state"></div>
</div>
```

the directive takes attribute "cust-label" that append it's value to the label beside the checkbox.
I'm using another directive to localize the text inside cust label called resource-key, it has another attribute called resource-attr. which takes the name of the attribute to add the resource-key value in.

Here's the 'resource-key' directive code:

```
.directive('resourceKey', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                //var $resValue = scope[attrs.resourceKey],
                //    $resAttr = attrs.resourceAttr || 'inner';
                //$resAttr == 'inner' ? element.html($resValue) : attrs.$set($resAttr, $resValue);
                element.attr('cust-label', 'hossam');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

The 'esf-cb' directive works well if cust-label attribute is hard coded inside the directive tag. but when I use the resource-key directive it compiles before adding the resource key to the label. So it doesn't render.
So How can I recompile 'esf-cb' directive after adding resource-key directive???.

Thanks :)

Comment: why do you need 2 directives for this?

Comment: cuz they are completly independent, resource-key is a standalone directive that's used across the whole app, not only in that tag, and I used it to localize the label on that checkbox directive